# Подсчет количества введенных символов

Tags: c, кодировка

Необходимо подсчитать, сколько раз в введенной строке встречается буква 'х'. Приведенный ниже код считает, сколько всего символов было введено. Подскажите, в чем ошибка.

```
 char str;
 int i;
 printf("Введите строку: ");
 for (i=0; (str = getchar()) != '\n';)
 if (str == 'х') i++;
 printf("\nБуква х встречается в строке %d раз\n", i);
```

Comment: @Rendez Vouz, в следующий раз описывайте ситуацию подробно (а то ведь заминусуют).

1) ОС (желательно какая локализация)

2) Компилятор 

3) Что предполагали получить

4) Что реально увидели.

---

getchar() читает 1 байт из потока, но возвращает тип int (кстати, EOF это тоже int (-1)), поэтому почти всегда читайте реультат getchar() в переменную типа int. В противном случае (читаете в char) русская буква 'я' в кодировке CP-1251 (она же ANSI или WINDOWS-1251) будет восприниматься как EOF.

Реально ощибка у Вас в другом (я описал в ответе), но все же...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно редкая ошибка, связанная с русской кодировкой (думаю это UTF-16).

Буква 'x' у Вас это русская 'х' (хэ) с кодом 1093 (dec) или 0x445 (См. таблицу Unicode [например здесь](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html)). Тут две проблемы в программе:

1) Как ввести ее с клавиатуры.

2) Она занимает 2 байта, а  str типа char содержит один байт.

Опишите подробнее в какой системе работаете, может подскажу, что делать.

**Кто заминусовал этот вопрос, пусть вернет баллы, лично я вопрос плюсую**

Comment: Ошибка как раз не редкая. Тут легко заплутаться с русской кодировкой и в досе, и в линуксе.

Comment: Пишется все под Windows.

Comment: Ээээ... Да там вообще с русской кодировкой полный идиотизм.

Comment: Советую пока не связываться с кириллицей, а во всех примерах использовать только латинские буквы.

Comment: Если под Windows, можно сделать SetConsoleCP(1251);, тогда кодировка ввода с консоли будет совпадать с кодировкой исходного файла.